# List method says "No Data Received" (even though it does receive) in WCF Service Application in Visual Studio 10

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, service

I've made a **WCF Service Application in Visual Studio 2010**. Every method works except this one:

```
public List<Friend> SendFriendList(int id)
    {
        FyfDataContext db = new FyfDataContext();
        List<Friend> friends = db.Friends.Where(P => P.PK_ID == id).ToList();
        return friends;
    }
```

It actually receives the data perfectly, but doesn't show it, when I test it in Google Chrome. 
[image: Proof that it receives data]

**Here's the twist:** Before this problem, I made the entire WCF Service App in Visual Studio 2012. And it worked perfectly there - but due to some other problems I had to go back to 2010.

Snippet of my IService.cs:

```
public interface IService2
    {
            [OperationContract]
            [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Friendlist?id={id}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
            List<Friend> SendFriendList(int id);
            [OperationContract]
            [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Friendloc?id={id}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
            Friendloc SendFriendLoc(int id); 
    }
```

The Friendloc method works - but like all the other methods, it returns an object, and not a list. 
I suspect that the problem is something with the web.config - but I just can't find out what. 
I do realize that VS12 made a 4.5 Framework, and VS10 made a 4.0. 
Here's the **Visual Studio 2010 Web.config:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="FyfConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Fyf.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name ="servicebehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restbehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name ="Fyf.Service1"
      behaviorConfiguration ="servicebehavior" >
        <endpoint name ="SOAPEndPoint"
        contract ="Fyf.IService1"
        binding ="basicHttpBinding"
        address ="soap" />

        <endpoint name ="RESTEndPoint"
        contract ="Fyf.IService2"
        binding ="webHttpBinding"
        address ="rest"
        behaviorConfiguration ="restbehavior"/>

        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange"
        binding="mexHttpBinding"
        address="mex" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

And here's the **Web.config from Visual Studio 2012:**

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="FyfdbConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Fyfdb.mdf;Integrated Security=True"

      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name ="servicebehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restbehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name ="Fyf.Service1"
      behaviorConfiguration ="servicebehavior" >
        <endpoint name ="SOAPEndPoint"
        contract ="Fyf.IService1"
        binding ="basicHttpBinding"
        address ="soap" />

        <endpoint name ="RESTEndPoint"
        contract ="Fyf.IService2"
        binding ="webHttpBinding"
        address ="rest"
        behaviorConfiguration ="restbehavior"/>

        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange"
        binding="mexHttpBinding"
        address="mex" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I've tried copying some of the elements from VS12 version to my VS10; such as aspNetCompatibilityEnabled to "true" and putting directoryBrowse in etc. But without luck. 
I'm sorry if it's something extremely simple that I'm missing. This is my first WCF Service. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you also tell something more about the client side of things?

Comment: @kroonwijk I could, but that is kind of irrelevant, since I'm connecting to the URL/method through browser. So I haven't used client side yet.

Comment: You are right, sorry. I think I'm going to reproduce this in a few hours from now, and play with it a bit.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciated. If you need more info, just ask.

Comment: Hmmm, works flawlessly with me on .NET 4. Can you include the source code for the Friend class please?

Comment: Really? That's weird. Could you perhaps post your web.config? Or is it the same as mine? 
Also, the Friend class is just my database table PK_ID bigint, FK_ID bigint, Friendstate int made into DBML (Linq To Sql).

Comment: My web.config is the same as your vs2010 one. I though the problem might be in the attributes of the friend class properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't quite know why this works, and the other method doesn't. 
Made a DataContract called Userlist with (almost) the same attributes (just tested it with ID). 
Definitely not as nice code, but it works. Still curious about the other problem though.

```
public List<Userlist> Friendlist(int id)
    { 
        int i = 0;
        FyfDataContext db = new FyfDataContext();
        List<Friend> friends = db.Friends.Where(P => P.PK_ID == id).ToList();
        List<Userlist> userlist = new List<Userlist>();

        while (i < friends.Count)
        {
            Userlist u = new Userlist();
            u.id = Convert.ToInt32(friends[i].FK_ID);
            userlist.Add(u);
            i++;
        }

        return userlist;
    }
```